# How to copy data from an array to core data entity

Tags: ios, json, core-data, swift3, magicalrecord

I'm fetching JSOn from a web call and parsing it's data as:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in

                if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                    switch(status){
                    case 200:

                        self.allResponse = response.result.value as! NSDictionary

                        if let categories = self.allResponse.value(forKey: "categories") as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                            for category in categories {
                                self.categories.append(Category(dict: category))
                            }
                        }

                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    default:
                        print("error with response status: \(status)")
                    }
                }
        }
```

The code fetches the data and parse it successfully. Now I want to save this data in CoreData entity that I've made. I've all the categories in `var categories = [Category]()` and I want to copy it into the entity of core data using magical records. I've saved values on CoreData before but they were one by one. Now I've all the data stack in an array which I need to store in coredata. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data like this.

```
 func saveToDataBase( _ saveData:[Category]){
        for data1 in data{

            let request:NSFetchRequest<Category> = Category.fetchRequest()
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", (id to check previously save or not)

            do {
                let count = try managedObjectcontext.count(for: request)

                if count == 0 {
                    // save data according to your requirement.
                    print(data1)
                }else{

                    //if anything you want to update then wright here
                }

            }catch{
                let error  = error as NSError
                print("\(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

I have already answer of this question.Hope it will help you. If you want to see coredata manager here i have made [sample project](https://github.com/tiwariammit/CoreDataManager)